# Find second highest value on a raster stack in R

Tags: r, raster

In R I can easily compute the max/min value of each cell in a georeferenced raster stack using the max/min commands.

```
set.seed(42)
require(raster)
r1 <- raster(nrows=10, ncols=10)
r2=r3=r4=r1
r1[]= runif(ncell(r1))
r2[]= runif(ncell(r1))+0.2
r3[]= runif(ncell(r1))-0.2
r4[]= runif(ncell(r1))
rs=stack(r1,r2,r3,r4)
plot(rs)
max(rs)
min(rs)
```

However, I have been trying to find a way to find the second highest values across a stack. In my case, each raster on the stack denotes performance of a particular model across space. I would like to compare the first vs second best values to determine how much better is the best model from its runner up without having to convert my stack to a matrix and then back into a raster. Any ideas or suggestions??

Comment: `max(rs[rs<max(rs)])` is one sloppy way.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work as r does not have defined methods to subset a stack using the syntax you suggested: ' Error in rs[rs < max(rs)] : object of type 'S4' is not subsettable'

Comment: Yeah, sorry -- you'd have to do some coercion on the attributes of the stack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll probably want to use `calc()`, adapting the code below to your precise situation. Just to show that it works as advertised, I've separately plotted layers formed by taking the highest, second highest, third, and fourth highest values found in each cell of the 4-layer `RasterStack` object.

```
zz <- range(cellStats(rs, range))

par(mfcol=c(2,2))
plot(calc(rs, fun=function(X,na.rm) X[order(X,decreasing=T)[1]]), main="1st",zlim=zz)
plot(calc(rs, fun=function(X,na.rm) X[order(X,decreasing=T)[2]]), main="2nd",zlim=zz)
plot(calc(rs, fun=function(X,na.rm) X[order(X,decreasing=T)[3]]), main="3rd",zlim=zz)
plot(calc(rs, fun=function(X,na.rm) X[order(X,decreasing=T)[4]]), main="4th",zlim=zz)
```

Or, more compactly and efficiently, just construct a new raster stack holding the reordered values and then plot its layers:

```
zz <- range(cellStats(rs, range))
rs_ord <- calc(rs, fun=function(X,na.rm) X[order(X,decreasing=T)])

par(mfcol=c(2,2))
plot(rs_ord[[1]], main="1st", zlim=zz)
plot(rs_ord[[2]], main="2nd", zlim=zz)
plot(rs_ord[[3]], main="3rd", zlim=zz)
plot(rs_ord[[4]], main="4th", zlim=zz)
```

[image]

Comment: This is beautiful. I had tried the raster:calc function but did not get it to work. This does exactly what I need while easily useful in similar situations.

Comment: Good. I agree that it's beautiful, and end up feeling that way every time I use **raster**. Do take care to include `na.rm` as a formal argument of whatever you function you supply via `fun=`, even if it doesn't end up being used anywhere in the function's body. `calc()` has code that checks for and requires an argument of that name.

Comment: I am really at awe at the comprehensiveness of the Raster package. Since I have discovered it, I have been a strong advocate for its use by colleagues, and often cringe thinking of my long and frustrating past experiences with Arcgis raster calculator and other inferior, costly and closed source alternatives... Thanks again.