# How can I find the pixel-wise maximum of multiple rasters?

Tags: r, spatial, raster

I have hundreds of rasters with same resolution and extent. It's a time series and each raster represent one point of time.

I know how to find the absolute maximum value in a raster.

But how can I find the maximum value in each cell in the entire time series of rasters?

If a1,a2,......a1000 are rasters, I want to create a raster x where each pixel is the maximum of all corresponding pixels of a1-a1000.

Comment: Look at `?pmax`. Try for instance `pmax(a1[],a2[],...)` where `a1`, `a2` and so on are your `raster` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you first put the rasters in a stack, you can then simply apply `min()` or `max()` to the stack to get the summary `RasterLayer` you're after

```
## Example rasters and stack
r1 <- raster(matrix(1:4,ncol=4))
r2 <- -2*r1
r3 <- 2*r1
rr <- list(r1,r2,r3)
s <- stack(rr)

## Extract the pixel-wise min and max values
min(s)
max(s)
```

(To apply some *other*, more complicated function that returns a scalar for each pixel in the stack, you may want to use `calc()`, as demonstrated (for example) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20482130/980833).)

Comment: Thanks ! I was using maxValue earlier. :)

Comment: I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33700755/how-can-i-find-the-pixel-wise-standard-deviation

Comment: Would there be a way to do the same but having a `raster list` instead of a `raster stack`? In my case, my rasters do not have exactly the same extent and I want to avoid `raster::resample` as processing time increases significantly

Comment: @GCGM Not sure, sorry. Perhaps work up a  minimal reproducible example, and post it as a question, here or, better yet, on https://gis.stackexchange.com/?