# Calculating global stats in raster bricks in R ignoring pixels value 0

Tags: r, raster

I am trying to calculate global stats (SD) in stack of 40 raster brick, without having to replace 0 to NA. Is there a faster way to do this than below? I can create a loop such that the globalSD is calculated for each brick separately. But it still does not solve the issue of ignoring 0 in my calculation.

```
rc <- function(x) { ifelse(x >0, cellStats(fSDstack, stat="sd"), ifelse(x <= 0,x,NA)) }

test <- calc(fSDstack,fun=rc)
```

Thanks
TiB

Comment: What's the purpose of the second `ifelse`? And are you sure you want to be ignoring zeroes in your calculation of SD? If you are treating zeroes are invalid, you could replace them with `NA` beforehand. i.e., `fSDstack[fSDstack == 0] <- NA; calc(fSDstack, sd)`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/33714515/489704 for speed.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(raster)
b <- brick(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))

# here using 255 instead of 0, as that goes better with the example data 
rc <- function(x) { sd(x[x != 255], na.rm=TRUE) }
test <- calc(b,fun=rc)
```