# How to find second highest value and corresponding layer name in a raster stack in R

Tags: r, stack, raster

I have a rasterstack with 12 layers and I would like to extract the 2nd highest value along with its corresponding layer name.
I found codes to order my values into 12 new layers in decreasing order:

```
rs_ord <- calc(inraster, fun=function(X,na.rm) X[order(X,decreasing=T)])
```

Now, if I could only do the same but return the corresponding layer's name, it would answer it all.

Thanks,
Pierre

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.

Comment: However, I don't seem to find a way to work it out.
if you could provide more information, that would be most appreciated. For instance, you suggest that I assign s[ ] to something... I thought 's' would be assigned to the rasterstack.
Thanks, Pierre

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find second highest value on a raster stack in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479255/find-second-highest-value-on-a-raster-stack-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the dimensions of your rasters, you may be able to use the following, which I'll demonstrate with dummy data in RasterStack `s`:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(replicate(12, raster(matrix(runif(100000), 1000))))

# coerce s to a data.frame
d <- s[]
# return the second-highest value
sort(d, decreasing=TRUE)[2]
# identify the column containing the second-highest value
col(d)[order(d, decreasing=TRUE)[2]]
```

If the raster's dimensions are too large to use the above approach, you can instead identify the highest two values of each layer in turn, and then work out which layer has the second-highest value:

```
# return a matrix whose columns contain the top two values per layer
top_two <- sapply(seq_len(nlayers(s)), function(i) {
  sort(s[[i]][], decreasing=TRUE)[1:2]
})
# return the second-highest value
sort(top_two, decreasing=TRUE)[2]
# identify the column containing the second-highest value
col(top_two)[order(top_two, decreasing=TRUE)[2]]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer(s). It does answer my question. Well done!
Yet, I realized that I did not state my question clearly. What I am looking for is the 2nd highest value for each cell  in the matrix.

The matrix contains class probability values. I have 12 layers, each corresponding to a class. The highest probability identifies the most likely class. However, in some areas, class probability can be as low as ~10% and still 'win'. I am interested in 'low' class probability, say, < 30-15%. I wonder if your sapply function can be adapted to return a matrix with 2nd highest col & value.

Comment: `calc(s, fun=function(x, na.rm) x[order(x, decreasing=T)[2]])` & 
`calc(s, fun=function(x, na.rm) order(x, decreasing=T)[2])` should get you what you're after. Will edit post later.

Comment: Hi again, 
Easy-peazy, once someone gives you the answer. It works.
Thanks, 
Pierre